# How to add select filter on Button name in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

How can I add the select filter on the button name? currently, the filter is appearing but it's showing the wrong value which is not working. Please see my code below.

```
  $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns([1,2,4).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select style="width:100%;"><option value=""></option></select>')
              .appendTo( $('thead tr:eq(0) td').eq( this.index() ) )
              .on( 'change', function () {
                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                  $(this).val()
                );
              column
                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                .draw();
              } );
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
          } );
        } ); 
            
        }
        
    
    } );
```

Table

```
<tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>28/12/2020</td>
      <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <button type="button" class="btn " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
            BUTTONNAME <img src="" />
            </button>
           
        </td>

        </tr>

     <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>28/01/2019</td>
      <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <button type="button" class="btn " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
            BTNNAME <img src="" />
            </button>
           
        </td>

        </tr>
```

I want to add a select filter on btn name i.e. BUTTONNAME, BTNNAME.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: it works. Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qu97xbyt/2/)

Comment: Hi, the sort is working, but I want a select filter on that column. In your case, It's Age.

Comment: what do you intend exactly for **a select filter on that column**? can you explain step by step in a simple way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with this line:

```
column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
          } );
```

When you console.log(d) it will show below:

```
"&lt;button type=\&quot;button\&quot; class=\&quot;btn \&quot; data-toggle=\&quot;modal\&quot; data-target=\&quot;#modal\&quot;&gt;
                BTNNAME &lt;img src=\&quot;\&quot;&gt;
            &lt;/button&gt;"
```

What you can do is convert this text into element by using jquery `$(text of element here, {html: true})`, html:true is used to convert the `&lt;` to `<` etc.

Once that is done, you need to check if the element is button, if yes, pass on the text of the button to the option.

Now, your problem with select is done.

Your next problem is when filtering or changing the value of the select.

On your current code, when a user changes the value of select it will scan the column and check for the EXACT cell value.

That won't work with your button as it is an element. What you can do is to check part of the text of the cell. So instead of using a regex `'^'+val+'$'`, just use the value itself as search parameter.

See below code:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  initComplete: function () {
    this.api().columns([1, 2, 3]).every(function () {
      var column = this;
      var select = $('<select style="width:100%;"><option value=""></option></select>')
      .appendTo($('thead tr:eq(0) th').eq(this.index()))
      .on('change', function () {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );
        column
          .search(val ? val : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });
      column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
        console.log(d);
        var cellElement = $(d, { html: true });
        if(cellElement.is("button")){
            var buttonName = cellElement.text().trim();
            select.append('<option value="' + buttonName + '">' + buttonName + '</option>');
        }
        else {
            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
          }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tzyqsajc/30/